# problems with VisualLightBox and Js downloads

Tags: jquery, html, download, overlay

I have three problems.

1- I'm French. =)

2- I'm creating a website for my work book (www.fabrice-y.fr). But my Js is too heavy and when we arrived on the webpage "Accueil" we can sea pictures before they are hided. So i created a false webpage to download it. It's not a good idea... =)
I need a HTML code to download the Js before we arrived on the main page. And this, for all browsers. Yes, I'm require. Is it possible?

3- I'm using an overlay to show my book's pictures. But I want to offer a fast navigation, so I have to limited clicks numbers. I tried to using VisualLightBox, but that don'k work when I put it in the webpage. It's other Js who prevent the functioning. Maybe I put too Js Links...

Thx for your help!

This is the code of the webpage :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="Bienvenu sur mon book,">
<title>My_Work_Book_Yao_Fabrice</title>

<!--[if lte IE 9]>

<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

<![endif]-->

<link href="../css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Start VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_files/vlb_files0/vlightbox0.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_files/vlb_files0/visuallightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="test_files/vlb_engine/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="test_files/vlb_engine/visuallightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- End VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->
        <!-- Start VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_files/vlb_files1/vlightbox1.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_files/vlb_files1/visuallightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!--script src="test_files/vlb_engine/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script-->
        <!--script src="test_files/vlb_engine/visuallightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script-->
        <!-- End VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->
        <!-- Start VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="book-test_files/vlb_files0/vlightbox0.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="book-test_files/vlb_files0/visuallightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!--script src="book-test_files/vlb_engine/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script-->
        <!--script src="book-test_files/vlb_engine/visuallightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script-->
        <!-- End VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->
</head>

<style type="text/css">
#en-tete #header ul li #page1{
    text-decoration: underline;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--<div id="animation"><img src="img/avion2.png" width="201" height="31" alt="bienvenue"></div>-->
<div id="wrapper"><!-- #BeginLibraryItem "/Library/en-tete.lbi" -->

</style>
<style type="text/css">
#voir-tete {
    position: fixed;
    left: 75px;
    top: 210px;
    color: #1B85C9;
    font: bold 12px 'Gruppo', cursive;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
<div id="logo"><img src="../img/logo.png" width="150" height="180" alt="logo" class="profil"><img src="../img/photo.png" width="150" height="180" alt="photo" class="face"></div>

<div id="voir-tete"><p class="vf">Me voir de Face</p><p class="vp">Me voir de Profil</p></div>

<div id="en-tete">
    <div id="header">
      <ul>
        <li ><a href="../acceuil/acceuil.html" id="page0">Accueil</a></li>
        <li ><a href="book.html" id="page1">Book</a></li>
        <li ><a href="../mon-parcours/mon_parcours.html" id="page2">Parcours</a></li>
        <li ><a href="../mes_videos/mes_videos.html" id="page3">Vidéos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="clear"></div><!-- #EndLibraryItem --><nav id="col800">

      <div class="titre 1">
  <h1 class="type 1">Logotype</h1>
  <h1 class="clic 1">Logotype</h1>

    <div class="voir 1"></div>
    </div>


        <!-- Start VisualLightBox.com BODY section id=0 -->
    <div id="vlightbox0">
    <a class="vlightbox0" href="book-test_files/vlb_images0/img_flore.jpg" title="Création de logo pour un fleuriste.
Le but étant de représenter l'activité du client tout en restant le plus simple possible. 

Réalisé en 2009."><img src="book-test_files/vlb_thumbnails0/img_flore.jpg" alt="Création de logo pour un fleuriste.
Le but étant de représenter l'activité du client tout en restant le plus simple possible. 

Réalisé en 2009."/></a>
<a class="vlightbox0" href="book-test_files/vlb_images0/img_gcf.jpg" title="Création de logo pour l'entreprise de Génie Climatique et Frigoriphique.

Ce Phoenix est présent grâce aux trois élements symbolisant la climatisation : l'eau, la flamme, et le flocon de neige.

Réalisé en 2010."><img src="book-test_files/vlb_thumbnails0/img_gcf.jpg" alt="Création de logo pour l'entreprise de Génie Climatique et Frigoriphique.

Ce Phoenix est présent grâce aux trois élements symbolisant la climatisation : l'eau, la flamme, et le flocon de neige.

Réalisé en 2010."/></a>
<a class="vlightbox0" href="book-test_files/vlb_images0/img_abfs.jpg" title="Création de logo pour l'Association de Futsal.

Basé sur le même style graphique que les logos de la coupe du monde de FIFA, ainsi que le drapeau Béninois en arrière plan.

Réalisé en 2012."><img src="book-test_files/vlb_thumbnails0/img_abfs.jpg" alt="Création de logo pour l'Association de Futsal.

Basé sur le même style graphique que les logos de la coupe du monde de FIFA, ainsi que le drapeau Béninois en arrière plan.

Réalisé en 2012."/></a>
<a class="vlightbox0" href="book-test_files/vlb_images0/img_majesticgd.jpg" title="Création de logo pour le magasin Decathlon à Thiais.

Parti sur un concept d'une équipe athlétique, le logo reprend la piste d'athlétisme ainsi que la couronne de laurier.

Réalisé en 2013."><img src="book-test_files/vlb_thumbnails0/img_majesticgd.jpg" alt="Création de logo pour le magasin Decathlon à Thiais.

Parti sur un concept d'une équipe athlétique, le logo reprend la piste d'athlétisme ainsi que la couronne de laurier.

Réalisé en 2013."/></a>
<a class="vlightbox0" href="book-test_files/vlb_images0/img_thiais.jpg" title="Création de logo pour l'entreprise Majestic.

Cette entreprise exerce plusieurs activités dont les constructions de routes, le crédit carbonne et la protection de la planète…

Réalisé en 2012."><img src="book-test_files/vlb_thumbnails0/img_thiais.jpg" alt="Création de logo pour l'entreprise Majestic.

Cette entreprise exerce plusieurs activités dont les constructions de routes, le crédit carbonne et la protection de la planète…

Réalisé en 2012."/></a>
<a class="vlightbox0" href="book-test_files/vlb_images0/img_gogslovegd.jpg" title="img_gogs-love-gd"><img src="book-test_files/vlb_thumbnails0/img_gogslovegd.jpg" alt="img_gogs-love-gd"/></a>
<a class="vlightbox0" href="book-test_files/vlb_images0/img_haydengd.jpg" title="img_hayden-gd"><img src="book-test_files/vlb_thumbnails0/img_haydengd.jpg" alt="img_hayden-gd"/></a>
<a class="vlightbox0" href="book-test_files/vlb_images0/img_hulkgd.jpg" title="img_hulk-gd"><img src="book-test_files/vlb_thumbnails0/img_hulkgd.jpg" alt="img_hulk-gd"/></a>
<a class="vlb" href="http://visuallightbox.com">rails lightbox gallery by VisualLightBox.com v5.6m</a>
    </div>
<script src="book-test_files/vlb_engine/vlbdata0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="titre 2">
  <h1 class="type 2">Print</h1>
  <h1 class="clic 2">Print</h1>

    <div class="voir 2">
    </div>
    </div>


    </nav>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/background.js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/site.js"></script>
    <!-- End VisualLightBox.com BODY section -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! That's a lot of code, but looking at what you describe - is it not an option to simply hide the elements using CSS first?

Comment: I'll try to put in my CSS right..

Comment: Tink you Pekka 웃 ! That works!! But Have you any solutions for the third question?